# Borrow errors for mutable refrence of struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutable-reference

```
struct C {
    p: String,
    q: String,
}

impl C {
    fn call(&mut self) {}
}

fn main(){
    let mut c = C { p: "p".to_string(), q: "q".to_string() };        
    let p = &mut c.p; // first mutable borrow occurs here
    let q = &mut c.q; // second mutable borrow doesn't occur here, why???
    c.call();         // second mutable borrow occurs here  // error[E0499]: cannot borrow `c` as mutable more than once at a time
    p.push('x');
    q.push('y');
}
```

`let q = &mut c.q;` second mutable borrow doesn't occur here, why??? I really can't figure it out, can someone explain why in depth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `let q = &mut c.q;` second mutable borrow doesn't occur here, why???

Because the compiler is smart enough to know that there isn't a mutable reference to `c.q`. There is one to `c.p`, but not to `c` or `c.q`. That is called a [split borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html): fields of a structure can be independently mutably borrowed.

Note:

- this only works intra-procedurally, split borrows don't exist at the type system level
- this will work with closures in rust 2021, thanks to [disjoint closure capture](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html)
- it may not work when involving smart pointers, for instance if `c` is a `MutexGuard`, split borrowing doesn't work, whereas a `Box` does

Fundamentally this is just a convenience, you could use pattern matching to hand-roll the split:

```
// assuming c is a smart pointer (box, mutexguard, ...)
// remove deref' for a plain C
let C { p, q } = &mut *c;
```

Comment: Actually, on the MIR lever pattern matching desugars to assignments and not the opposite.